A Multiple Intent Query to Multiple Single Intent Query
Problem Description
I am designing an algorithm that inputs an string, looks in the Q&A dataset, and brings back the closest Q&A to our user query.
However, when the user sends a multiple-intent query like:

"Tell me about price, warranty, and delivery time."

The algorithm only returns a single Q&A, even though the query contains multiple intents.

Objective
To handle such cases, I need a way to split a multiple-intent query into multiple single-intent queries. For example, the query above should be split into:

"Tell me about price"
"Tell me about warranty"
"Tell me about delivery time"

This will allow the algorithm to process each intent individually and return the closest Q&A for each.
